# Double Consonants in Gerund

Tags: british-english, orthography, conjugation, transatlantic-differences, doubled-consonants

Is there any rules regarding gerund that tell when to double the consonant of a word and when not to?

I'm a little bit confused regarding this matter. Based on this [link](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/beginning-opening-gerund-doubled-last-consonant.2797746/) there are words that can be spelled with or without double consonant. An example given was "traveling" and "travelling" which was discussed further [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/traveling-or-travelling-doubling-a-final-consonant-when-adding-a-suffix.543819/) while there are words that are required to be doubled and words that are required not to have double consonants like beginning and opening. Or should I just follow this rule,

> -If the base verb ends with consonant + stressed vowel + consonant, double the last letter.
>       (This does not apply when the last syllable (thus last vowel) is not stressed.)
>       but,
>
> -If the base verb ends in vowel + consonant + e, omit the e.

and think that "travelling" is wrong (even though we knew that it is accepted in normative English).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Travelling" is not wrong and "Travelling" vs "Traveling" is a "British English" vs "American English" thing as well-explained in the linked [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences):

> The **British English doubling** is used for all inflections (-ed, -ing,
>   -er, -est) and for the noun suffixes -er and -or. Therefore, British English usage is cancelled, counsellor, cruellest, labelled,
>   modelling, quarrelled, signalling, traveller, and **travelling**.
>   *Americans typically use* canceled, counselor, cruelest, labeled,
>   modeling, quarreled, signaling, traveler, and **traveling**.

I think the linked article, ["Why do some words have double consonants while others have only one?"](http://a4esl.org/q/h/9807/km-doubles.html) seems to be a good starting point. You have to get yourself familiarized with all those examples.

It is important to note that, in two-syllable words such as happening or entering, etc.

> If the stress is on the first syllable, the word gets only one
>   consonant + -ing.

"Travelling" is an exception. There is no rule but has some exceptions.