# Why is the 'L' in detailed not doubled?

Tags: british-english, orthography, conjugation, transatlantic-differences, doubled-consonants

I cannot quite understand why the 'L' is not doubled when forming 'detailed' from 'detail'. Is that an exemption to the consonant doubling, or did I simply not understand the rules?

From the answers to 
[When is "L" doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled)

> When you have a verb that ends in a vowel plus "L" and you are going to add an ending that begins with a vowel then you double the "L".

Example: "They have *tunnelled* under the wall."
vs
"They have *detailed* the plan to tunnel under the wall."

Comment: I think the British doubling rule may only apply to words with a *single* vowel before the l. I don't know for sure as I'm American.

Comment: Isn't the 'ai' a diphtong, and is phonetically like a single vowel?

IPA according to wictionary: [ˈdi(ː)teɪɫ]
where 'eɪ' as in day, pain

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323880/double-consonants-in-gerund

Comment: @sumelic So you might learn something from the answer to this question? (i.e. surely it's worth an upvote for a brand new user?)

Comment: Cheers Archie. The answer links to http://a4esl.org/q/h/9807/km-doubles.html

Does the second rule from that page apply here?
Two-syllable words:

>ED = If the stress is on the first syllable, the word only gets one consonant + ED.

Comment: I'm a Brit, and I wasn't aware of that rule! But anyway, rules always have exceptions!  I can't answer the Q. except to say **Because!** - sometimes these things just are.  Maybe this is a case of "It's the exception that proves the rule."

Comment: @gschenk No, the rules for L are an exception in British English. :) They don't work like the rules for P, T, K, S, B, D J (and so forth). For the rules, see below!

Comment: @TrevorD L is an exception in English - see below :-)

Comment: Mainly because there is no such rule, only a "tendency".

Comment: @HotLicks Not in BE it ain't.  (It's not a 'rule' any more or less than any other spelling rule in English) but it's a lot more than a tendency!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In British English, in which L is often doubled before inflectional suffixes, it is normally only doubled when there is just *one* of the letters A, E, I, O, U directly before the last consonant before the suffix:

- *detail[ed]* (two of these letters, A & I, behind the suffix - no double L).
- *travel[led]* (just one E before the suffix, therefore double L).

L is an exception in British English. It doesn't behave for doubling purposes  like other consonants, for example P, T, K, B, D, G. Importantly, it does not matter whether the syllable it occurs in is stressed or not.

American English does not have this L doubling rule. In American English, as with other consonants, the L is only doubled if the syllable before the suffix is stressed.

There are also, as always with English spelling, exceptions to the rule.

Comment: The word *travelled* was used as an example for an exception in the two syllable rule mentioned in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323880/double-consonants-in-gerund

I wonder if the reason is that the stress shifted to the first syllable, as it derives from *travailler*, where the stress is on the second sylable.

Comment: @gschenk Maybe! (I don't know, but it might be an idea :)

Comment: @gschenk FYI, that rule that applies to other consonants only works if there is a single vowel before the consonant, not a a double one ... :-)

Comment: *"...directly behind the last consonant..."* "Behind"? They're in *front* of the last consonant, not behind it.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some good rules of thumb for knowing when to use a doubled consonant (from David Crystal's book *Spell it Out*). The OP's example either has a long vowel or falls under exception 1(c). Interestingly the French cognate of the word (*détaillé*) has the double *l*.

1. (a) To indicate that the previous vowel is short (*hopping* vs. *hoping*), except (b) in words consisting of a single closed syllable ending in nasals or plosive (*pan*, not *pann*, but *scuff* and *bill*), and except (c) when the short vowel is written with two letters (*breaded*), and except (d) when the consonant itself is written with two letters (*dishes*), and except (e) when the consonant is *v* or *x* (*axes*, *devil*).
2. Except not in sets of related words formed from adding (or not) Latinate suffixes (*athlete* vs. *athletic*).
3. Except not in some later French and Latin loan words (*proper* vs. *pepper*)

Comment: Thank you, this puts the rule discussed in the other answer in a wider context, explaining the reasons for it. I find this rather helpful, and appreciate it.

Comment: @gschenk This answer is very good for explaining why *uninflected* words like *pen* or *till* have a double or single letter at the end. However, it won't explain why the N in *panned* needs to be doubled, or why the L in *tunnelled* is doubled. The rule for doubling is different before inflections.

Comment: If you put in the info about your rules applying to words without inflectional suffixes, then I will upvote it!

Comment: Nice data. It won't explain the double L in tunelled or travelled, for example, though. You say "pan not pann" but the verb is "panning" or "panned" but  not "paning" or "paned". These rules from Crystal refer to words before they get inflections, not afterwards. (This is why Crystal gives pan and not pann and bill and not bill and has the rules about plosives and nasals).

Comment: @Araucaria I'd guess that *panned* had two syllables at the time its spelling was fixed.

Comment: @Araucaria: Re: "These rules from Crystal refer to words before they get inflections, not afterwards": That's not true. Its examples include *hopping*, *hoping*, *breaded*, and *dishes*, all of which have inflectional endings.

Answer (score 0):

The comments pointed me to an answer to my own question (ta!).

Exceptions to the doubling rules are discussed in
[Double Consonants in Gerund](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323880/double-consonants-in-gerund) .

Relevant here is the rule:

> Two-syllable words:
>   ED = If the stress is on the first syllable, the word only gets one consonant + ED.

(from http://a4esl.org/q/h/9807/km-doubles.html)

In British English the stress is on the first sylable of detail,  [ˈdi(ː)teɪɫ] (source wictionary).

As an amusing aside, in American, the stress is apparently on the second sylable: If consonants were doubled in American English, it would be *detailled* in the US and *detailed* in the UK, wouldn't it?

**Please note:**
While writing this I have been informed by Araucaria that these rules would not apply to this problem. Please consider above in the light of that comment.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work for L. L is an exception in (British) English. For this reason there is a double L in words like *tunnelled*, which has first syllable stress. There's a double L in *travelled*, which also has first syllable stress. In American English that rule won't work either, because *detailed* has second syllable stress, because like in British English, we only find double a consonant when there is a *single* vowel before that consonant!

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Isn't the stress for *tunnel* on the second syllable?

Would you explain the single vowel, wouldn't it need to be writable with a diaeresis to be phonetically two vowels? That is *detaïled*, which it is not.

Comment: No, in *tunnel* it's on the first.

Comment: No one said anything about phonetic vowels! I made the point in my post by using capital letters to refer to letters. This is a spelling rule which relates to letters (and which only vaguely relates to pronunciation in the case of L). I've got to split, but if you've more questions, leave them here and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: I suppose I must have been influenced by my native German there. There it is certainly on the second, expressed by the spelling 'Tunell' (in Austria and Switzerland, in Germany it is spelled Tunnel, while being pronounced alike).

Comment: Is there a known explanation/specific reason that while the doubling rule is typically used where the spelling follows the phonetics, the spelling of the word takes precedence in this case? (Not that I expect that there is a known reason, just asking in case there might be.)

One might find examples where one homophone has its 'L' doubled, while another's remains singular after appending the -ing or -ed.

Comment: There may well be, but I don't know! :-)