# Interrailler or Interrailer, which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is true to express people who make Interrail travel?

One "l" or double "ll".

Also some of pages are typing as InterRaillers, interraillers. Should I start with upper case for both Interrail and Interraillers in the sentence?

Example:

Interraillers love travelling the Europe's hidden places.

Comment: See "[Why is the 'L' in detailed not doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332298/why-is-the-l-in-detailed-not-doubled)" for the general rule about when to double L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*-ail* + *-er* = *-ailer*, with just one L; hence *jailer*, *mailer*, *trailer*, etc. So, it would be *Interrailers*.